# How to create class property with pre-defined enum value?

Tags: c#

Wondering if it's possible to have a class' property that returns an enum type and can only contain values from an enum type.

```
public enum items { item1, item 2, item 3}

public class bundles 
{ 
  public items selections 
  {
    get [return selected enum]
    set [selected enum value]
  }
}
```

and when bundles() gets called, hopefully it can be like this:

```
bundles bunch = new bundles 
{ 
  selections = [intellisense drops the items enum as default options] 
};
```

Something like this:
[image]
Appreciate very much, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `public items selections { get; set; }`?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: What do you mean by "*returns an enum type and can only contain values from an enum type*" ? Because a variable of an enum type can only be one of an enum value, else if it have a flag attribute... or else if you use a cast from a int out of bounds that is still accepted. So do you ask for how to check if the value for the setter is in bounds of the enums defined values ?

Comment: Enum are checked by the compiler and not during run time.  You would have to add a validation method to verify if values are correct.

Comment: I don't see what's the problem here when you have a property that is an enum intellisense does suggests the enum values on object initialization

Comment: @sweeper's comment is correct. However there's nothing to stop a consumer of your class from saying `var b=new bundles(); b.selections = (items)42;` if you want to prevent that, you'd need to add code to your `set`ter that would throw an out of range exception if the value was put of range

Answer (score 0):

Gotit...
It was staring at my face all the while. THAT is the code I was looking for.
.selections will automatically pull the enums as value option.